# Installing a Network Manager that works in the terminal on Debian9

Tags: debian, wifi, networkmanager

Trying to find any Network Manager on the "apt" databases that works in the terminal. I usually use "NetworkManager-tui" but I can not find it.

Do anyone have a suggestion on good alternatives for WiFi management on Debian 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkManager-tui presents in ***network-manager*** package as `nmtui` utility. You can use `nmcli` utility which is a part of the ***network-manager*** package too and provides *CLI* interface instead of *ncurses*. But ncurses interface is more friendly for beginers.

Ensure that `NetworkManager` service is started before using NetworkManager utilities:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager
```

If it will be stopped try it to start:

```
systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

The `network-manager` package provide :

[nmtui](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/network-manager/nmtui.1.en.html)

> nmtui - Text User Interface for controlling NetworkManager

[nmcli](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/network-manager/nmcli.1.en.html)

> nmcli - command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager

**alternatives**

[wpa_cli](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/wpasupplicant/wpa_cli.8.en.html)

> wpa_cli - WPA command line client

Arch-linux wiki: [connecting with wpa_cli](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli)

[wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_passphrase)